# gcloud unable to add cluster to a blank kubectl configuration

Tags: google-app-engine, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have created a GCP Cluster via logging into my GCP project > Container Engine > Create Cluster. But when I want to work with it via `kubectl`, I can't seem to add it to my configuration.

Using the Google Cloud SDK, I have properly authenticated, set my project, default region/zone, can I can see my cluster:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
gcloud config set compute/region us-east1
gcloud config set compute/zone us-east1-b
gcloud config set project <myproject>
gcloud container clusters list
gcloud container clusters get-credentials <cluster name>
gcloud config set container/cluster <cluster name>
```

So all of this works fine.

I have a *blank* `~/.kube/config` as I wanted to troubleshoot a problem and start over, therefore, my kube config is:

```
kubectl config view
...
apiVersion: v1
clusters: []
contexts: []
current-context: ""
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: []
```

My problem is that I'm following [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/clusters/operations) (see "Configuring kubectl" section) and therefore I want to inform kubectl about my new cluster. So per the documentation there, I successfully run:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials NAME --zone ZONE
...
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
kubeconfig entry generated for <clustername>.
```

Yet when I run `kubectl config view` I still see everything blank:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters: []
contexts: []
current-context: ""
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: []
```

Why can't I start from a completely blank kubectl configuration and add my GCP cluster to it?